# How to mask an image in IOS sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, uiimage

I want to apply an image filter or mask when a word drawn on the image.The word will have transparent effect to see through the background image.
Is it possible in native IOS sdk or i need different api to perform this.
This image consist of 2 images. one is where India is written over, and another one is which is see through India letter.[image: This image consist of 2 images. one is where India is written over, and another one is which is see through the India letter.]

This is the code i am using to generate image from text.

```
-(UIImage *)imageFromText:(NSString *)text{
// set the font type and size
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:100.0];  
CGSize size  = [text sizeWithFont:font];

// check if UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions is available (iOS is 4.0+)
if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,NO,0.0);
else
    // iOS is < 4.0 
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

// optional: add a shadow, to avoid clipping the shadow you should make the context size bigger 
//
 CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0), 5.0, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx,kCGBlendModeNormal);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);


/*NSLog(@"Rect  %@",CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx));
CGImageRef alphaMask = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
CGContextClipToMask(ctx, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx), alphaMask);*/


// draw in context, you can use also drawInRect:withFont:
[text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) withFont:font];

// transfer image
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

return image;}
```

It is working fine, however i need to generate the image which will have black background and transparent text to see through it.

Comment: thank you guys. it's working. 2 images all we need one is masking image with black background and letter embedded and another one is original image on which masking will work. Could it be possible to make the masking image dynamically from code?

Answer (score 13):

You can use this code(got from [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html)),

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage; 

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Swift 4 and I get the original image as the masked image.