# Is it possible to add a transparent layer or view above a colored view?

Tags: ios, core-animation, avfoundation

I'm using AVFoundation framework to scan a barcode, but that may be unrelevant for my problem.

**What I want:**

I would like that the square bordered in green be transparent (not with the darkened black).

[image]

**Here is what I have done:**
I have 2 views: `backgroundView`( which occupies the whole screen) and `highlightView` which is the square bordered with green, on top of `backgroundView` (I have used a XIB for dimensions and positions) :

```
self.highlightView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
self.highlightView.layer.borderWidth = 3;
// this following line does not allow the square to be transparent
self.highlightView.layer.opacity = 0;

// relative to AVFoundation
_previewLayer.frame = _backgroundView.bounds;
[_backgroundView.layer addSublayer:_previewLayer];

_previewLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
_previewLayer.opacity = 0.3;
```

**UPDATE :** xib (here representing the square with a clear color background), the backgroundView has the property black color background).

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `self.highlightView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` ?

Comment: I edited my question to add more precision.

Comment: In that case you are looking in the wrong direction. You can possibly achieve your goal by playing around with the layers of a single view. Don't try with a second (`self.highlightView`) view on top. I'll let you know if I can come up with a solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned, you were looking in the wrong direction. There are multiple posts with a problem similar to yours, which have pretty decent answers. (You will have to study and understand to make the most of them):

- [Cut Out Shape with Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375777/cut-out-shape-with-animation)
- [Simply mask a UIView with a rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391058/simply-mask-a-uiview-with-a-rectangle)

To sum it up, you need to apply the semi-transparent color to the layer of `backgroundView` and then play around with the layer's `mask` property to get the work done.

You can find many tutorials to learn using the `layer` and `mask` together.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, it seems very promising ! I will study the references you gave.