# Reverse Image Masking

Tags: ios, uiimage, masking, quartz-core

In IOS SDK, I am able to mask an image but not able to reverse image mask. i mean, i have one make image which have rectangle part and now i mask image and i get attached image but i want reverse result.

I get image as result.
[image]

while i need this as result.

[image]

Please help me to achieve it.

...Edit...
My code

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.imageView.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, self.imageView.frame.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGImageRef maskImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"] CGImage];
CGContextClipToMask(context, self.imageView.bounds, maskImage);

   CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, self.imageView.frame.size.height);
   CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

[[self.imageView image] drawInRect:self.imageView.bounds];

UIImage *image11 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

self.imageView.image = image11;
```

Thanks

Comment: How did you mask the image? Show your code!

Comment: Please look on it. i have edit my question and add my code..

Comment: Can you not just draw the image and then draw a white rectangle over it?

Comment: Thanks, but it is not white rectangle. it is an background color on view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved it in two steps. May not be the best way to do it, but it works.

1. Invert your mask Image.
2. Mask

Look at the code below.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:i(@"test1.jpg")];
    _imageView.image = [self maskImage:i(@"face.jpg") withMask:[self negativeImage]];
    [self.view addSubview:_imageView];
}
```

The method below is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6672628/641062)

```
- (UIImage *)negativeImage
{
    // get width and height as integers, since we'll be using them as
    // array subscripts, etc, and this'll save a whole lot of casting
    CGSize size = self.imageView.frame.size;
    int width = size.width;
    int height = size.height;

    // Create a suitable RGB+alpha bitmap context in BGRA colour space
    CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *memoryPool = (unsigned char *)calloc(width*height*4, 1);
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(memoryPool, width, height, 8, width * 4, colourSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);

    // draw the current image to the newly created context
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), [self.imageView.image CGImage]);

    // run through every pixel, a scan line at a time...
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        // get a pointer to the start of this scan line
        unsigned char *linePointer = &memoryPool[y * width * 4];

        // step through the pixels one by one...
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            // get RGB values. We're dealing with premultiplied alpha
            // here, so we need to divide by the alpha channel (if it
            // isn't zero, of course) to get uninflected RGB. We
            // multiply by 255 to keep precision while still using
            // integers
            int r, g, b;
            if(linePointer[3])
            {
                r = linePointer[0] * 255 / linePointer[3];
                g = linePointer[1] * 255 / linePointer[3];
                b = linePointer[2] * 255 / linePointer[3];
            }
            else
                r = g = b = 0;

            // perform the colour inversion
            r = 255 - r;
            g = 255 - g;
            b = 255 - b;

            // multiply by alpha again, divide by 255 to undo the
            // scaling before, store the new values and advance
            // the pointer we're reading pixel data from
            linePointer[0] = r * linePointer[3] / 255;
            linePointer[1] = g * linePointer[3] / 255;
            linePointer[2] = b * linePointer[3] / 255;
            linePointer += 4;
        }
    }

    // get a CG image from the context, wrap that into a
    // UIImage
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *returnImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

    // clean up
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    free(memoryPool);

    // and return
    return returnImage;
}
```

The method below taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872975/how-to-mask-an-image-in-ios-sdk).

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);


    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

}
```

Comment: Thanks Vignesh, I have tried your code but getting same result with invert color... do you have any suggestion...

Comment: Try printing the inverted mask image and check whether it inverts alpha of your mask. The other way is construct a path (using Bézier curves) and do a EO Clip. I can also share my mask image if you need it.

Comment: Hi... Can you please suggest any solution for IOS 7. Because it is not working on IOS 7....

Comment: Any Idea About reverse masking. (I want the transparent area with fill.),In above method it gives the mask area only....please help me.

Comment: Inverting colors has nothing to do with masking the image. How did this get to be the accepted answer?